# Azure Data Lake - how to insert into external table in AzureSQL DB?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

From Azure Data Lake, inserting records to an external table in AzureSQL DB produce the following error:

```
Error   E_CSC_USER_CANNOTMODIFYEXTERNALTABLE    Modifying external table 'credDB.dbo.BuildInfosClone' is not supported.
Modifying external table 'credDB.dbo.BuildInfosClone' is not supported.
External tables are read-only tables.
```

How to insert records to external database ? My credential has read-write access. I am using regular Azure SQL DB, not Data Warehouse.

Complete U-SQL code

```
CREATE DATA SOURCE myDataSource
FROM AZURESQLDB
WITH
(
    PROVIDER_STRING = "Database=MedicusMT2",
    CREDENTIAL = credDB.rnddref_admin,
    REMOTABLE_TYPES = (bool, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, decimal, float, double, string, DateTime)
);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbo.BuildInfosClone
(
    [Key] string,
    [Value] string
)
FROM myDataSource LOCATION "dbo.BuildInfosClone";

INSERT INTO dbo.BuildInfosClone
( [Key], [Value] )
VALUES
("SampleKey","SampleValue");
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently write directly to Azure SQL Data Warehouse tables using U-SQL.  You could either write your data out to flat file then import it using Polybase or use Data Factory to orchestrate the copy.

Alternately you can use Azure Databricks to write directly to SQL Data Warehouse as per [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/databricks-extract-load-sql-data-warehouse#load-data-into-azure-sql-data-warehouse).

Comment: How about inserting to Azure SQL Database, (not Data Warehouse) ?

Comment: This tutorial talks about loading data from Data Lakeinto external DW table using U-SQL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-load-from-azure-data-lake-store

Comment: The tutorial you reference is referring to T-SQL.  For example, click on the link "CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE" in the tutorial - it will bring you to the T-SQL reference material.

Comment: Polybase ADLS connection is only supported in SQL DW today. Azure SQL DB does not offer Polybase support. Please go and upvote the feature request to insert into a staging table from U-SQL via external Data Sources at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.

Comment: @MichaelRys I upvoted this one instead: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/13745238-support-output-to-sql-and-sql-dw

Comment: @MichaelRys fyi, Product Owner decided not to use Data Lake due to this limitation. Our target DB are multiple instances of Azure SQL DB, one for each customer. Each DB has multiple report tables with identical schema. It is very cumbersome to have U-SQL to flatten output to csv files per each customer-table combination and create individual DataFactory pipeline for every one of those files.

Comment: Let us know what you come up with instead!

Comment: @wBob we ended up with RhinoETL framework instead. Although not as convenient as U-SQL, it provides a way to code back-and-forth logic transition between `T-SQL` and `C#`. Its as lightweight, portable, and scalable as a C# app. https://ayende.com/blog/3102/rhino-etl-2-0